# Expansion of a function analytic at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

Having a bit of trouble with a problem in my complex variables class:

Prove that if f(z) is analytic at infinity, then it has expansion of the form

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{z^{n}}$$

converging outside some disk.

I know that for $f(z)$ to be analytic at infinity we want to consider the composite function $g(w) = f(\frac{1}{w})$, then if $g$ is analytic at 0 f will be analytic at infinity.

I've been attempting to Taylor expand $g(w)$ around the point w=0 and then substituting the appropriate f terms in. However I'm not sure if this is a valid method as I can't see much pattern in the derivatives.

So far I have

$$g(w) = g(0) + g'(0)w + \frac{g''(0)w^{2}}{2} + \frac{g'''(0)w^{3}}{3!} + ...$$

as well as

$$g'(w) = \frac{-f'(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{2}}$$
$$g''(w) = \frac{2f'(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{3}} + \frac{f''(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{4}}$$
$$g'''(w) = \frac{-6f'(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{4}} - \frac{6f''(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{5}} - \frac{f'''(\frac{1}{w})}{w^{6}}$$

Which appears to be giving me the right $z^{-n}$ terms but with each additional derivative I gain more of the previous $f$ derivative so I'm not entirely sure this method is going anywhere. Any help getting moving in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$, so $$g(w) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n w^n$$ in a disk with centre $0$. Substitute $w = \frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: Perhaps try the mapping $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer So upon substituting $w=\frac{1}{z}$ I get the desired result except now it will be analytic on the exterior of the disk? We are then asked to find such an expansion for a couple of functions, namely $$\frac{z-1}{z+1} \& \frac{z^{2}}{z^{2} -1}$$ which I assume i proccede with by performing the transformation to $g$ then finding the expansion before changing back again? Thanks

Comment: If the expansion of $g$ converges on $D_r(0)$, the expansion of $f$ converges on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \overline{D_{1/r}(0)}$, so (unless $r = 1$) it's not the exterior of the same disk. For the given functions, you can also directly get the expansion around $\infty$, e.g. $$\frac{z^2}{z^2-1} = \frac{1}{1-z^{-2}},$$ and expanding that into a geometric series gives you the expansion directly.

Comment: @DanielFischer could you post the first comment as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered? thanks.